# Torch error and warnings. (TTS code with huggingface model.)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, huggingface-datasets

I have python code:

```
from transformers import SpeechT5Processor, SpeechT5ForTextToSpeech, SpeechT5HifiGan
from datasets import load_dataset
import torch
import torchaudio
import soundfile as sf
import speechbrain as sb
from speechbrain.pretrained import SpeakerRecognition

processor = SpeechT5Processor.from_pretrained("microsoft/speecht5_tts")
model = SpeechT5ForTextToSpeech.from_pretrained("microsoft/speecht5_tts")
vocoder = SpeechT5HifiGan.from_pretrained("microsoft/speecht5_hifigan")

text_input = input("Enter text in English: ")

inputs = processor(text=text_input, return_tensors="pt")

spk_rec = SpeakerRecognition.from_hparams(source="speechbrain/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb", savedir="pretrained_models/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb")

embeddings_dataset = load_dataset("vctk", trust_remote_code=True)

wav = sb.dataio.dataio.read_audio(embeddings_dataset['train'][5841]['file'])

speaker_embeddings = spk_rec.encode_batch(wav.unsqueeze(0))

speaker_embeddings = speaker_embeddings.squeeze(0)

num_tokens = inputs["input_ids"].shape[1]

speaker_embeddings = speaker_embeddings.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2).unsqueeze(3).unsqueeze(4).expand(1, 1, 1, 1, num_tokens, 192)

spectrogram = model.generate_speech(inputs["input_ids"], speaker_embeddings)

with torch.no_grad():
    speech = vocoder(spectrogram)

sf.write("output.wav", speech.numpy(), samplerate=16000)
```

but I have error and warnings. If I run code first I have warnings:

```
The torchaudio backend is switched to 'soundfile'. Note that 'sox_io' is not supported on Windows.
C:\Users\mceca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\speechbrain\utils\torch_audio_backend.py:22: UserWarning: torchaudio._backend.set_audio_backend has been deprecated. With dispatcher enabled, this function is no-op. You can remove the function call.
  torchaudio.set_audio_backend("soundfile")
The torchaudio backend is switched to 'soundfile'. Note that 'sox_io' is not supported on Windows.
C:\Users\mceca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\speechbrain\utils\torch_audio_backend.py:22: UserWarning: torchaudio._backend.set_audio_backend has been deprecated. With dispatcher enabled, this function is no-op. You can remove the function call.
  torchaudio.set_audio_backend("soundfile")
C:\Users\mceca\Desktop\py.py:9: UserWarning: torchaudio._backend.set_audio_backend has been deprecated. With dispatcher enabled, this function is no-op. You can remove the function call.
  torchaudio.set_audio_backend('soundfile')
```

next when I enter text, I have error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mceca\Desktop\py.py", line 33, in <module>
    with torch.no_grad():
  File "C:\Users\mceca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mceca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\transformers\models\speecht5\modeling_speecht5.py", line 2921, in generate_speech
    return _generate_speech(
  File "C:\Users\mceca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\transformers\models\speecht5\modeling_speecht5.py", line 2521, in _generate_speech
    decoder_hidden_states = model.speecht5.decoder.prenet(output_sequence, speaker_embeddings)
  File "C:\Users\mceca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mceca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mceca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\transformers\models\speecht5\modeling_speecht5.py", line 700, in forward
    speaker_embeddings = speaker_embeddings.expand(-1, inputs_embeds.size(1), -1)
RuntimeError: expand(torch.FloatTensor{[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 192]}, size=[-1, 1, -1]): the number of sizes provided (3) must be greater or equal to the number of dimensions in the tensor (7)
```

This is my first time to work with torch, torchaudio and huggingface TTS model. Please, modify my code and describe your changes (not only describe).